# Setting background image to div in css leaving an offset in left and right

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a set of `div`s in html 5 having class name `submenuButton`. I want to add a common background image to these `div`s using css. I tried the following:

```
.submenuButton{
     background-image:url(images/but-up-center.png); 
     background-position: 5px 0px;
     background-repeat:repeat-x;
     background-size: contain;
}
```

This sets the `div` image leaving 5px from the left and extends to the end of the button. But I want to have this image ended at 5px from the right also.

So, could anybody suggest what can be done in the css so that it leaves 5px space both on the left and the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `background-clip: content-box;` in combination with a 5px padding left and right.

This would give you the following code:

```
.submenuButton{
    padding: 0 5px;
    background-image:url(images/but-up-center.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-size: cover;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

More information on `background-clip` can be found on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

[Example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duzznp56/1/)

Comment: The `padding`/`content-box` combo is a good one...never thought to use it like that +1

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a pseudo

```css
.submenuButton {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
.submenuButton::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    background:url(http://placehold.it/200/) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="submenuButton"></div>
```